# One liner required to get last working day for previous month

Tags: awk, date, cal

E.g. today is 06/04/2018; the desired output is 05/31/2018.

For 07/01/2018 the output should be 06/29/2018.

Comment: There is production issue, I can't write a script which exceed the limit 512 words in Autosys command, though script is also welcome

Answer (score 3):

To find the last workday (assuming the work week is Monday to Friday), output the last 3 days of the previous month (descending), and find the first non-weekend day

```
for m in {1..12}; do
    firstMonthDay="2018-$m-01"
    for i in {1..3}; do 
        read dow date <<<"$(date -d "$firstMonthDay - $i days" "+%u %c")"
        if [[ $dow -le 5 ]]; then 
            echo $date
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

```
Fri Dec 29 00:00:00 2017
Wed Jan 31 00:00:00 2018
Wed Feb 28 00:00:00 2018
Fri Mar 30 00:00:00 2018
Mon Apr 30 00:00:00 2018
Thu May 31 00:00:00 2018
Fri Jun 29 00:00:00 2018
Tue Jul 31 00:00:00 2018
Fri Aug 31 00:00:00 2018
Fri Sep 28 00:00:00 2018
Wed Oct 31 00:00:00 2018
Fri Nov 30 00:00:00 2018
```

Adjust your desired output date format where I use `%c`

I use the last 3 days of the month because that's the most we need to iterate: Sunday the 31st, Saturday the 30th, Friday the 29th.

---

Let's encapsulate into a function:

```
lastWorkdayPreviousMonth() { 
    local first fmt dow date i opt OPTIND=1

    while getopts :d:f: opt; do
        case $opt in 
            d) first=$OPTARG ;;
            f) fmt=$OPTARG ;;
        esac
    done
    : ${first:=$(date "+%Y-%m-01")} ${fmt:="%c"}

    for i in {1..3}; do
        read dow date <<<"$(date -d "$first- $i days" "+%u $fmt")"
        if [[ $dow -le 5 ]]; then
            echo $date
            break
        fi
    done
}
```

Then

```
$ lastWorkdayPreviousMonth
Thu May 31 00:00:00 2018
$ for m in {1..12}; do lastWorkdayPreviousMonth -f "%d/%m/%Y" -d 2018-$m-01; done
29/12/2017
31/01/2018
28/02/2018
30/03/2018
30/04/2018
31/05/2018
29/06/2018
31/07/2018
31/08/2018
28/09/2018
31/10/2018
30/11/2018
```

Comment: If a script is OK, put the function code into a script file .

Answer (score 3):

The following one-liner will print the last working day of previous month.

```
 day=`date -d "$(date +%m/01/%Y) -1 day" | awk '{print $1}'`; if [ $day == Sat ]; then  D=`date -d "$(date +%m/01/%Y) -2 day" "+%m/%d/%Y"`;echo $D; elif [ $day == Sun ]; then  D=`date -d "$(date +%m/01/%Y) -3 day" "+%m/%d/%Y"`;echo $D; else D=`date -d "$(date +%m/01/%Y) -1 day " "+%m/%d/%Y"`;echo $D; fi
```

Sorted Code:

```
day=`date -d "$(date +%m/01/%Y) -1 day" | awk '{print $1}'`; 
if [ $day == Sat ]; then  
    D=`date -d "$(date +%m/01/%Y) -2 day" "+%m/%d/%Y"`;
    echo $D; 
elif [ $day == Sun ]; then  
    D=`date -d "$(date +%m/01/%Y) -3 day" "+%m/%d/%Y"`;
    echo $D; 
else 
    D=`date -d "$(date +%m/01/%Y) -1 day " "+%m/%d/%Y"`;
    echo $D; 
fi
```